# Getting Value from a sorted TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a sorted map

```
Map<RangeValues,String> cIndexes = new TreeMap(new StartIndexComparator());
```

where key is an object of the class containing two integer values.

```
public class RangeValues {


    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
}
```

So, when i am trying to access the value from that map, I am getting null as a value.

```
Set<RangeValues> keySet = cIndexes.keySet();
RangeValues[] keys = keySet.toArray(new RangeValues[keySet.size()]);

for(int index = 0; index < keys.length-1; index++)
{
   **cIndexes.get(keys[index]) // this is giving null**
   int nextIndex = keys[index+1].getStartIndex();
}
```

Implementation of comparator is

```
public class StartIndexComparator implements Comparator<RangeValues> {

    @Override
    public int compare(RangeValues r1, RangeValues r2) {

        if(r1.getStartIndex() > r2.getStartIndex())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

filling of map

```
RangeValues range = new RangeValues();
range.setStartIndex();
range.setEndIndex();
cIndexes.put(range,conjunctions.get(conjIndex));
```

How can I get the value from that map using object as key.

Comment: As per my understand "keys[index]" give some unexpected value.Please check with debug.

Comment: Is it possible to see your implementation of the comparator and the values that you used to fill the map (with a small program demonstrating the problem)? See http://ideone.com/oOAHJg; it's working perfectly.

Comment: I have edited the question and added comparator implementation in it.

Comment: @ZouZou..Thanks for bringing my attention towards implementation of Comparator ...I had not considered the case of r1.getStartIndex() == r2.getStartIndex()..The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override equals and hashCode methods in your object that is being used as a key

```
public class RangeValues {


    private int startIndex;
    private int endIndex;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + endIndex;
        result = prime * result + startIndex;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        RangeValues other = (RangeValues) obj;
        if (endIndex != other.endIndex)
            return false;
        if (startIndex != other.startIndex)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

The above equals and hashCode methods assume that both startIndex and endIndex will take part in deciding whether two objects of your class are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not fulfilling the `equals` / `hashCode` contract in your `RangeValues` class.

Threfore, there is no guarantee that `cIndexes.get(keys[index])` will not return `null`.